# Etymology of ending "-keit" in relation to ending "-heit"

Tags: etymology

It appears that in general adjectives can be nominalized by adding the suffix *-heit*, which however changes to *-keit* in case the adjective already has been formed by use of a suffix, like *-bar*,*-ig*, *-lich*, *-sam*.

As stated in etymology-on-line for the English suffix *-hood*, and by Kluge's Etymological Dictionary of the German Language, *-heit* has its origin in an independent noun (hade? in old English), the same root occurs in the German adjective *heiter* and has cognates in other Indo-European languages.

Is there any etymological evidence (earlier forms of German) showing how *-keit* developed from *-heit*?

Answer (score 4):

The etymology of the ending *"-keit"* is rather complicated, as we have influences from a different pronunciation in High German *vs.* Low German dialects here.

#### Example "Ewigkeit":

Up until today the adjective ending *"-ig"* is pronounced differently in northern and southern regions. See for example *"ewig"*:

> - Pronunciation in standard German: **[ˈeːvɪç]** (same a **ch** in *"Ich"*).
> - Pronunciation in Swabia: **[ˈeːvɪk]** (same as **ck** in *"dick"*).

Now, for *"ewig"* the pronunciation in Old High German was different from today, as we can see from the Middle High German spelling **ewic**, or **ewik**. The adjective was then nominalized using the common suffix *"-heit"* to give **Ewic-heit** which then became **Ewikeit** by dropping the **h** on pronunciation.

Only later the now missing **g** from *"ewig"* was reintroduced to become *"Ewi**g**keit"*. Until today this added **g** curiously is pronounced as "ch" in standard German: **[ˈeːvɪçkaɪ̯t]**. Interestingly in many German dialects *"Ewigkeit"* is still pronounced as **[ˈeːvɪkaɪ̯t]**, i.e. the  **g** introduced from spelling is ignored.

#### Other variants

This phenomenon happened to many adjectives, including other adjectives that did not end on **-ic** leading to an independent additional suffix **-keit**, and even another independent suffix **-igkeit** was introduced (e.g. *"Gerechtigkeit"*, *"Farbigkeit"*). In other cases the **-keit** suffix was dropped again for **-heit** (e.g. *rein* > *Reinic-heit* > *Reinekeit* > *Reinheit*), or both suffixes coexisted at times (*Frommheit - Frömmigkeit, Munterheit - Munterkeit*). On top of all this confusion it may also be that when pronounced as **ch** the ending may also be spelt with **ch** (*vrœlīc-heit > Fröhlichkeit*).

For a concise insight into the etymology of "**-keit**" and many more examples see:

- [Grimms Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK03319)

#### Indo-European etymology

In Old High German *-heit* already is present, sharing it's roots with the adjective **heiter**, and the Old Saxonian **hēd**, Old English **hād**, Gothic **haidus**, and Old Norsk **heiðr**. All these, and Old Indian **kētúḥ**, or Latin **caelum** probably go back to a common Indo-European root **(s)kāi-**.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=-heit)</sup>

#### Summary

In summary we can see that the suffix **-keit** shares the same etymology with **-heit** but it's spelling changed over time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this explains it better for you.

**[-*keit*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-keit) is a result of a wrong segmentation of two Middle High German suffixes -ec (-ig) and -heit: -ec-heit was interpreted as -e-keit.**

*-keit* seems to be the equivalent to the English *-ness*

The reference for *-heit* is [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-heit)

Answer (score -1):

I think a connection between -heit and heiter is erroneous. Semantically there is no connection at all.
In Latin adjectives can have a noun with the suffix -tas/tatis as in sanus, adj. and sanitas, genitive sani-tat-is. I assume that this suffix  derives from status/u:s
meaning state or condition. Sanitas is the state or condition of being sanus.

And I think that German -heit is connected with Latin -tat-i that might give tait and heit if t is dropped and h is used to show that there was a plosive.
So Gesundheit or Krankheit simply means the state of being well or sick and it has nothing to do with "heiter" (cheerful). I consider -keit just a variant of -heit in certain special positions.